# SimpleXMLElement (string) casting not working as expected

Tags: php, casting, simplexml

Here is the print of a SimpleXMLElement:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Amount] => 6.00
)
```

This is what I am doing:

```
$amount = (string) $xml->Amount;
echo $amount;
```

I can see **6.00** without any issue on screen but functions still see this value as 0 (false) even if I am using casting. I double-checked it as follows:

```
$amount = $xml->Amount;
var_dump($amount);
// Returns » object(SimpleXMLElement)#189 (1) { [0]=> string(4) "6.00" }  

$amount = (string)$xml->Amount;
var_dump($amount);
// Returns » string(4) "6.00"

$amount = (string)$xml->Amount[0];
var_dump($amount);
// Returns » string(4) "6.00"
```

It should work but it doesn't and I don't know why. Immediately after the casting, I'm using $amount to calculate a percentage value but I always end with $amount and $percentage equal to 0 (zero).

Edit. Here is the requested part of code:

```
$amount = (string) $xml->Amount;
$amount = $amount / $rate;
$amount = number_format($amount, 2);

$percentage = ($amount * (1 / 100)) + 0.10;         
$percentage = $percentage / $rate;
$percentage = number_format($percentage, 2);
```

p.s. $rate is another variable that is 100% fine, correct and that always exists. It doesn't come from SimpleXMLElement.

Comment: "Immediately after the casting, I'm using $amount..." - please post this part of the code.

Comment: Done. Thank you for your answer